# lowpass prototype to bandpass filter

Tags: filter, low-pass, band-pass

[image: Given low pass prototype Hp(s) =1/s+1. Determine each of the following analog filters and plot their magnitude from 0 to 200 rad/sec.]

Bandpass filter with a center frequency of 10 rad/sec and bandwidth of 20 rad/sec here, wo= is mentioned as geometric frequency that's why I am confused.

The solution in which picture is correct?

[image]

Comment: Is there any question remaining?

Comment: All your "question" contains is a statement that you are confused. Nobody but you knows what that confusion is or what it relates to so, please focus on asking a question. The picture is also largely unreadable and, maybe you can explain how it relates to your confusion but, ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

The arithmetic mean for center frequency is:
$$ \omega_o = {{\omega_H - \omega_L}\over 2} $$
The arithmetic mean is not right for describing the center frequency of a bandpass filter.

Geometric mean for the center frequency is (correct description):
$$ \omega_o = \sqrt{\omega_H \omega_L} $$

Bandwidth is:
$$ BW = \omega_H - \omega_L  $$

Solving for \$ \omega_L \$ with the above two equations:
$$ \omega_L = {{\sqrt{BW^2 + 4\omega_o^2}-BW} \over 2} $$

Plugging in your numbers for \$BW = 20\$ and \$\omega_o = 10\$:
$$ \omega_L = 4.1421 $$
$$ \omega_H = 24.1421 $$

That should answer your confusion about the geometric mean which is normally how the bandpass filter center frequency is specified.

To go from low-pass prototype, design an R-C low-pass filter for the desired bandwidth (\$BW\$). To turn it in to a bandpass filter, resonate the capacitor with an inductor at \$\omega_o\$.

The example below uses Hz, not radian frequency, but it gets the point across in doing a low-pass filter to bandpass filter transform for a simple R-L-C filter. This technique can be applied to higher order filters.

[image]